# How to find element by xpath in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium in Python to click on a link to a report on a web page. I have it working up to the point where it opens the page that the report is on, but I am having trouble actually clicking that specific report.

The page has a list of reports all with the same class. This is what I get when I inspect that specific report for example:

```
<a class="rpt" href="reportConfigRedirect.asp?action=filter&amp;rc_id=181786&amp;letter=">Run with new filters</a>
```

I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
```

and this doesn't seem to work, it doesn't do anything once it gets to that page with the report.

Comment: have you tried, right clicking, inspecting the elemnent and then copying the xpath?

Comment: Yes, I did that and pasted the xpath to my code above, it did not do anything when it got to that point

Comment: You may need to add wait(s) for that element. Can you share the xpath that you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induce `WebdriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`.Use the following Xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='rpt'][contains(.,'Run with new filters')]")))
element.click()
```

If unable to click using Webdriver try use javascript executor.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='rpt'][contains(.,'Run with new filters')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
```

---

**EDITED**

---

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(.,'Run with new filters')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
```

OR

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@hef,'reportConfigRedirect.asp?action=filter')][contains(.,'Run with new filters')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
```

Comment: Great thanks, the second option worked and was able to click the report now. There is a final link now to the report and I tried to apply the same to this but now this one isn't clicking. This is the inspect code : <a href="reportConfigRedirect.asp?action=filter&amp;rc_id=181786">Run with new filters</a>